# Validate decimal numbers in Yii with regex

Tags: php, regex, yii

I have tried

```
array('Number', 'match', 'pattern'=>'(^\d*\.?\d*[0-9]+\d*$)|(^[0-9]+\d*\.\d*$)'),
```

as I want to only allow positive values with the format of 1.00, 4.34, 234.98

I get this error though

```
preg_match(): Unknown modifier '|'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern should be enclosed by slashes, ie:

```
array('Number', 'match', 'pattern'=>'(/^\d*\.?\d*[0-9]+\d*$)|(^[0-9]+\d*\.\d*$)/')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using number_format to print your numbers you could use:

`[['formfield'], 'number', 'numberPattern' => '/(^\d+\,\d+\.\d+$)|(^\d+\.\d+$)/'],`

It works with 1,234.56 or 234,56